# How should I partition my drive for my Ubuntu installation?

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows

So firstly I'm going to dual boot windows and Ubuntu (Windows already installed) and am wondering how I should partition my other drive, which is completely empty.

Do I just need one massive partition, or smaller partitions?  Its formatted as NTFS or whatever it is, the Windows standard.

I'm planning to install Ubuntu 13.04 and am relatively new, Ive used Wubi but now I want the real experience.

Just one quick bonus question, how can I distinguish between drives in the installation process. I've heard bad stories about choosing the wrong drive. Also I cannot disconnect and hard drives as I'm not going to go fiddle around inside my laptop :)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Are they 2 different physical disk or 2 partitions on the same disk?

During the install process you will be asked how to part the disk. the safest way is to use the automatic partitioning which detects your existing OS and does not overwrite it.

Choosing the manual way:
If it is your first installation I would keep it simple and create just a / and a /home partition, plus a small swap (at least your ram size, if you plan to hibernate).
Just be sure to double check you are not going to format the existing win partition and mount it as /windows

the installer will then take care of setting up the dual boot environment